# Get IP Address of the requested client(Soap message)

Tags: web-services, soap, inbound, clientip

I am working on creating soap message and need a find a requested client IP.
I have been finding a way to find a client IP but still can't.
Could you let me know steps how i can find a client ip when get a request from client?

Comment: Why are you creating a SOAP message by hand? Why not just use "Add Service Reference"?

Answer (score -1):

So you want to be able to look at the IP address of the client consuming the web service, from within the service?

You could create a class like this that examines some of your server variables, some of which pull data from HTTP headers.  I've found that just looking at HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and REMOTE_ADDR does the trick (ex. in C#):

```
public class IP
{
    public static String UserHostAddress { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress; } }
    public static String REMOTE_ADDR { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_CLIENT_IP { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_X_FORWARDED { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]; } }
    public static String HTTP_FORWARDED { get { return HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]; } }

    public static String IP_ADDRESS
    {
        get
        {
            if (HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR != null)
            {
                return HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR;
            }

            return REMOTE_ADDR;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, I just realized I didn't interpret what he was asking correctly.